# Fasttext UnicodeDecode issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, word2vec, fasttext

I am trying to load the fasttext file to use it as word embedding first time. I have this:

```
KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(binary_file_path,
binary=True, encoding='utf-8', unicode_errors='ignore')
```

I also tried what is described here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20071/how-do-i-load-fasttext-pretrained-model-with-gensim
Still same results
I have downloaded the .bin file from kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/kambarakun/fasttext-pretrained-word-vectors-english)
But still I am having the issue:
`'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 0: invalid start byte`
I want to use only the .bin file and not .vec file as it takes less time.

Comment: Are you sure the file you're loading is in the word2vec binary format? Where exactly did you get the file(s)? (Gensim has other classes for loading true FastText models, too – which would be necessary to retain all FastText features.)

Comment: @gojomo Got files from https://www.kaggle.com/kambarakun/fasttext-pretrained-word-vectors-english
I tried to download from https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md as well but kept getting .zip.part folder which is incomplete. If there is any other way to download it, then do let me know.
Gensim has other classes means FastText so you are saying to use `fasttext.load_fasttext_format`?

Comment: Since the Kaggle dataset seems to just be a mirror of the original, I'd personally suggest preferring the original source, and figuring out why that download is failing. No `gensim` load methods will take a `.zip` file, so you'd want to unzip that before attempting a load. And since the `.bin` file is explicitly a FastText format, I wouldn't expect any `load_word2vec_format()` method to work on it. You should try the FastText-specific load methods.

Comment: @gojomo: I run out of memory if I use fasttext.

Comment: Then the full FastText model you are trying to load is likely too big for your system. If you chose to load just the `.vec` text file instead (via a `load_word2vec_format()`), it might fit - but then you'd not be getting the full benefits of FastText, such as constructed vectors for out-of-vocabulary words. If you want to use this full FastText model,  and you're currently getting out-of-memory errors, you'll have to work on a machine with more memory.